erfcinv is giving incorrect results in MATLAB
I am working on a Communication Theory problem. To summarize the problem, I have to code the following:

Plot the ideal bit error probability for BPSK, which is given by $Q(\sqrt{\frac{2E_{b}}{N_{0}}})$ , on a log scale as a function of $\frac{E_{b}}{N_{0}}$ in dB over the range 0-30 dB.

Find the value of $\frac{E_{b}}{N_{0}}$ that corresponds to an error probability of $10^{−2}$ and $10^{−5}$


I implemented the first part of the problem using the following code:
% Define the range of Eb/N0 in dB
EbN0_dB = 0:0.00001:30;

% Convert Eb/N0 from dB to linear scale
EbN0_linear = 10.^(EbN0_dB/10);

% Calculate the ideal bit error probability for BPSK
bit_error_prob = 0.5 * erfc(sqrt(EbN0_linear));

% Plot the results on a logarithmic scale
semilogy(EbN0_dB, bit_error_prob);
xlabel('Eb/N0 (dB)');
ylabel('Bit Error Probability');
title('Bit Error Probability for BPSK');
grid on;

I get the above formula by using the fact that: $Q(x) = \frac{1}{2} \text{erfc}(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})$ found here, where $x=\sqrt{\frac{2E_{b}}{N_{0}}}$
Running the code, I get the following graph:
Image Link
Now, when I use this graph to get approximate the value of $\frac{E_{b}}{N_{0}}$ that corresponds to an error probability of $10^{−2}$ and $10^{−5}$, I get the values 4.3 and 9.5 roughly, respectively. But when I use the following code to find it:
ber1 = 0.01;
ber2 = 0.00001;
x1 = (erfcinv(2*ber1))^2;
x2 = (erfcinv(2*ber2))^2;

I get the values as
    2.7059
    9.0946

which is VERY different from the actual answer. I am pretty sure that the formula I am using is correct, so what is happening here? Im

I am familiar with Matlab but BPSK is an acronym I don't know. Be kind : give a reference.

Why don't you answer my little question ?

Your code is OK, although 15 dB (horizontal scale) is more than enough for BPSK. So 30 dB is way to much, below BER=1e-12 we don't care anymore.
The values differ because you compare linear values with dBs: your graph-value of 4.3 dB is linear equal to 2.7 (second block of code). Same for the pair 9.5 dB / 9.0 (linear).
